# How to set the interface name in `kickstart.cfg` file?

Tags: centos, kickstart, interface

How to set the interface name in `kickstart.cfg` file?

We know if we install CentOS system in a Server, there maybe `eth0`, `ens0`, `ensxxx`, `eno1` and so on.

I have questions,

1. Why there will generate different interface names? why not all `eth0`?
2. Is it possible configure the interface name in the `kickstart.cfg`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using CentOS 7. There are five naming conventions for network interfaces in RHEL/CentOS7. There is a precedence which the kernel will try to use for naming with the ethX naming being used as the last resort. Read more [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-consistent_network_device_naming). Yes, it is possible to use the name in your kickstart for configuring the interface; but you either need to configure what the naming convention will be and/or know what name the kernel will select.